# How to split a full address to city, zip code in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tableau's paid version. I have a lat, lon for an address and the full address it self. I want to display a map view with the ability to drill down to state and zip code code level. I cannot create a hierarchy as the state and zip code fields are not available separately. Any clue how to move forward.

Comment: Can you share a sample address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your full address is just one big text field, you have to split it into separate feilds first and then build a hierarchy. Depending on the quality of your data you can either do it outside Tableau in your original datasource or use calculated fields.